# Getting GPS co-ordinates via SMS and show on google map

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, sms

I am trying to show GPS co-ordinates on google map. I am getting GPS co-ordinates via SMS. Building and app generation is done correctly but after launching app on real device(android kitkat), the google map don't show up anything and once I receive GPS co-ordinates via SMS the app crashes displaying "unfortunately map has stopped".Here is my code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     
OnMapReadyCallback {

static private GoogleMap mMap;
int index=0;//index of SMS recieved
int index2=0;
char[] Lat=new char[15];
char[] Lon=new char[15];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Get the data (SMS data) bound to intent
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        String str = "";
        String format = bundle.getString("format");

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            Object [] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            msgs= new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String format = myBundle.getString("format");
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], format);
                }
               // else {
                 //   messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                //}
                strMessage += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                strMessage += " : ";
                strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                index=strMessage.indexOf(":");
                index2=strMessage.indexOf(",");
                strMessage.getChars(index,index2,Lat,0);//extracting latitude from Latitude: to ,
                index=strMessage.lastIndexOf(":");//getting last index of : which will be Longitude:
                index2=strMessage.length();//getting the length of string
                strMessage.getChars(index,index2,Lon,0);//extracting longitude from : to last char of string
                strMessage += "\n";
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            update_location();
        }
            } // bundle is null
        }
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng venkateshnagar = new LatLng(20.8781753,15.3481637);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(venkateshnagar).title("random location for startup"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(venkateshnagar));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(venkateshnagar,18));
}




 void update_location(){
 double Lat1=Double.parseDouble(Lat.toString());
 double Lon2=Double.parseDouble(Lon.toString());
    LatLng found=new LatLng(Lat1,Lon2);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(found).title("this is current location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(found));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(found,18));
    }
   }
```

What I have done wrong.

Comment: Add the crash log to your question.

Comment: Your `getSMS` Receiver must be `public`, which is most likely what's causing the crash upon SMS receipt. Don't know about your map.

Comment: @ Mike M: if I made it public then Manifest shows this class is not found. How to access this class then?

Comment: @ADG: Actually due to PC problems I am not able to test the app on emulator so I am using it on real device. So how crash Log of real device can be shown?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I don't know why your IDE is telling you that. It's gotta be explicitly `public`, otherwise it's `protected`, and can't be instantiated by the system, which is what your stack trace would be telling you. Try cleaning/rebuilding after adding the `public` modifier. (Btw, there can't be any spaces between the @ and the username, or they won't get the message. I just happened to come back and check.)

Comment: I just realized I misspoke in my last comment. No modifier is package-private, not `protected`. Same outcome, though.

Comment: @MikeM. I think I should start developing step by step. So first I am trying to show google map in my app. But its showing blank screen with google name in left down cornor. I searched alot on this website, with no luck for any solution worked.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? [SO1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216826/sending-gps-coordinates-via-sms) and [SO2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667685/how-can-i-use-my-gps-coordinates-via-sms-body-android)

Comment: @d.datul1990 I am able to successfully send GPS co-ordinates via SMS to other smartphone. But this other smartphone is not able to recieve those co-ordinates from SMS and show on google map. Moreover my google map is always showing blank screen so I am trying to make it ok first.will you be able to help me about google maps?

Comment: I have successfully started google maps in my app. The problem was in SHA1 fingerprint. Actually the key I was using to sign my app got different SH1 fingerprint using which I had enabled google map API from console.But as the SH1 fingerprint was different than API there was a authorization problem and hence the map was not starting and showing blank screen. To cope up with it I created new keys and also defined those for release and debug apk from file->Project structure->signing. So now I will be going on next part where I am facing problem. getting GPS via SMS and showing on map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its working. I have used `MarkerOptions options` in `update_location()` method of my program. And then byusing `options.position(found)` Here is the updated method:

```
public void update_Loc()
   {                                               // Instantiating MarkerOptions class
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Lat.toString()+Lon.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    double Lat1=Double.parseDouble(Lat);
    double Lon2=Double.parseDouble(Lon);
    LatLng found=new LatLng(Lat1,Lon2);
    options.position(found);
    Marker mapMarker=mMap.addMarker(options);
    options.title("This is the current location");
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(found,26));
}
```

I hope it will others who are trying to make application like me.